# XmlWriter - disposable

Tags: c#, xmlwriter

I am having trouble understanding the way XmlWriter works in C#. Take the following code as if it hypothetically was used somewhere.

```cs
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
settings.Indent = true;

XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings);

// Do stuff

writer.Close();
```

Since XmlWriter is not used within an `using` statement, could this potentially result in an `OutOfMemoryException` due to it not being properly disposed?

Comment: Close, is almost same as Dispose in this case, but using "using" is syntactic sugar and makes sure that you won't miss close. Also, I should add, that close is needed not only for disposing some references, but for signaling to stream, that everything is finished and all data should be sent completely. Only then you can use builder value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, the purpose of the `Dispose()` in this case is to allow the `XmlWriter` to assume *ownership* of whatever it is writing to - for example, if you create an `XmlWriter` over a `Stream`, calling `Dispose()` on the `XmlWriter` can (by default) flush the xml writer *and then call `Dispose()` on the stream*. This makes it easy to pass an `XmlWriter` to APIs without also having to pass them a chain of other objects they need to dispose when they're done (it could, for example, be an `XmlWriter` talking to a `CompressionStream` talking to a `SslStream` talking to a `NetworkStream`, etc).

In *the general case*, the purpose of the `Dispose()` on the **final end thing** is to close the underlying resource (which could be a file, a socket, a pipe, etc)

In this specific case, you're talking to a `StringBuilder`. The `Dispose()` here is basically a no-op, as there *is no external resource*. It'll just be collected by the GC either way, at some point in the future. As such, no: there is no memory leak problem here; the GC can  see what you're doing.

So: **in this case** it won't make a functional difference, but: it is good practice to get into the habit of calling `Dispose()`  (usually via `using`) when that is part of the API, as in many cases this is *really, really important*.

Answer (score 0):

Its good to have `using` block, where it ensures calling the `Dispose` on any object that implements `IDisposable`.

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(builder, settings))
{
     //do stuff
}
```

The `Dispose` method for `XmlWriter` looks like-

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (this.WriteState != WriteState.Closed)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Close();
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could potentially cause memory issues if there would be an exception in

```
// Do stuff
```

In this scenario, the Close method would not be executed.
Using statement is a syntactic sugar around try-finally blocks. It calls Dispose in finally block even there was an exception

[XmlWriter.Dispose calls Close method behind the scene](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.xml/System/Xml/Core/XmlWriter.cs,8068f03feebca075)

Answer (score 0):

according to c# docs 
The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs within the using block. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler. The code example earlier expands to the following code at compile time (note the extra curly braces to create the limited scope for the object):

```
        {
            var font1 = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
            try
            {
                byte charset = font1.GdiCharSet;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (font1 != null)
                    ((IDisposable)font1).Dispose();
            }
        }
```

and close function is do the same thing 
This method calls Dispose, specifying true to release all resources. You do not have to specifically call the Close method. Instead, ensure that every Stream object is properly disposed. You can declare Stream objects within a using block (or Using block in Visual Basic) to ensure that the stream and all of its resources are disposed, or you can explicitly call the Dispose method.